# Round up to the nearest year

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Hi all i've searched the web but have been able to come up with a solution to this issue. Basically i want to round a number of days to the nearest year. So if i have a value of 250 days, this should round up to 1 year or if i had 400 days this would round up to 2 years. Any ideas?

Comment: what about leap years? What is "a year"?

Comment: 400 is closer to 365, why does it round up to 2 years? Do you wish 1 day to round to 1 year?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Years vary in length - should 366 days be one year or two?

Assuming a 365-day year, you would want something like:

```
int years = (days + 364) / 365;
```

... that ensures that an *exact* number of years doesn't round at all, but anything else rounds up.

Another alternative would be:

```
int years = (int) Math.Ceiling(days / 365.0);
```

Comment: This will 'round' 0 days into 0 years - which seems correct indeed, but I think the person asking should be aware of this, seeing as it should always be rounded -up- to a full year according to his example.

Comment: @AndersHolmström: That's the normal meaning of "rounding" to an integer value - if the exact value is already an integer, it stays at that value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, now that Jon Skeet commented I obviously don't stand a chance... :(

As noted in comments below, his solution is the one that should be looked at. If anyone was doubting this...

```
int days = 400;
int roundedYears = (days / 365) + 1
```

Comment: Hmm, yes - but i used % on accident at first. This seems to work to me (not accounting for 366 day years). What do you mean am I missing?

Comment: It's off if days is an exact number of years, as explained in Jon's answer.  Just use Math.Ceil, if nothing else it makes the code more readable.

Comment: That is a very valid point indeed, thank you. :) I'm mostly feeling dizzy from having commented at the same moment as Mr. Skeet. I'll go get some fresh air and rethink my life.